# Change Label When Selecting Text In A Combo Box VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I have a combo box with two selections. When selecting a option from the drop down, I want a label's text to change accordingly above it. Is there an easy way to do this with an event maybe?

I appreciate any replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

You need to write this code in combobox selectedIndex change event

eg:

```
Protected Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged
        Label1.Text= DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text.ToString()
End Sub
```

and You need to set `DropDownList.AutoPostBack=true` in PageLoad Event

Comment: combobox.SelectedItem.Text errored, but combobox.SelectedItem didn't. Still helped me figure it out, thanks

Comment: I'm using it for an If statement, and just figured out that this is works fine for me:  If combobox.SelectedItem = "Text"

Answer (score 1):

change depending on your controls..

```
Private Sub YourComboBox_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles YourComboBox.Click

    UrLabel.Text = YourComboBox.SelectedValue

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**Asp.net**

**ComboBox**

You need to set **AutoPostBAck = "true"**

```
<table>
            <tr>
                <td><asp:ComboBox ID="cmb" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
            <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:ComboBox></td>

        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

**.aspx file (Code behind)**

```
Protected Sub cmb_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmb.SelectedIndexChanged
        lbl.Text = cmb.SelectedValue
    End Sub
```

**Asp.net**

**DropDownList**

You need to set **AutoPostBAck = "true"**

```
<table>
            <tr>
                <td><asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
            <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList></td>

        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

**.aspx file (Code behind)**

```
Protected Sub ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ddl.SelectedIndexChanged
        lbl.Text = ddl.SelectedValue
    End Sub
```